# Intermittent crash using AVFoundation to create a UIView that contains a QR

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, crash-reports, core-image

I am running into a very intermittent crash in a program that is using AVFoundation to create a UIView that contains a QR code from a passed in String.  It does not happen often, but happens over time as my TestFlight users use the App.

Here is the crashlog from the Xcode 9 organizer.

[image: crash log]

I created a protocol with and extension to handle the creation of the QRCode and place it into a UIView. My UITableViewCell conforms to the QRCodeImageProtocol

```
protocol QRCodeImageProtocol : class {
func generateQRCode(from string: String, forImageViewSize imageViewSize: CGSize) -> UIImage?
```

}

```
extension QRCodeImageProtocol {

func generateQRCode(from string: String, forImageViewSize imageViewSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let generatorKey = "CIQRCodeGenerator"
    let inputMessageKey = "inputMessage"
    let inputCorrectionLevelKey = "inputCorrectionLevel"
    let qrCodeCorrectionLevel: String = "M"

    if let data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1),
        let filter = CIFilter(name: generatorKey, withInputParameters: [inputMessageKey : data, inputCorrectionLevelKey : qrCodeCorrectionLevel]),
        let qrCodeImage = filter.outputImage {

        let x = imageViewSize.width / qrCodeImage.extent.size.width
        let y = imageViewSize.height / qrCodeImage.extent.size.height

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: x, y: y)

        let output = qrCodeImage.transformed(by: transform)
        return UIImage(ciImage: output)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then in my UITableViewCell, I monitor the string I am using to create the QR Code and call the protocol function to return the image upon the strings value changing, and lastly I set the UIImageView's view to that QRCode image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var qrCodeImageView: UIImageView!

    var recordName: String? {
    didSet {
        if let qrString = recordName {
            qrCodeImageView.image = generateQRCode(from: qrString, forImageViewSize: qrCodeImageView.frame.size)
        }
    }
}
```

This works 99% of the time, but after a day or so of running the App without any crashes coming back to me in the crash log reporter - I get a crash, then another, then another spaced hours or a day or days apart.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?  This is Xcode 9 Swift 4.x NON-beta versions.  The testers are running iOS 11.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not calling any code that creates/sets views from a background thread. Is it possible that the `didSet` is called from a non-main thread? I'd wrap the contents of the `didSet` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` to confirm that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I wanted to expand on Dylan's response with my experience. In my code (Objective C), the AVCaptureDevice `videoPreviewLayer` was being dynamically added to the UIView when the QR code read started.

```
 _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
[_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_imgScan.layer.bounds];
[_imgScan.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];    
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

That was being done on the main thread. What caused my error was that, when the read process stopped,  `videoPreviewLayer` was being removed from the super layer on another thread. This was causing a layout error `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, "reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'"

I finally figured out that `[_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer]` should have also been done on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`:

```
 -(void)stopReading{
     [_captureSession stopRunning];
     _captureSession = nil;
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self->_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            });
```

(I hope I am making sense.)